# XPathNavigator and UnderlyingObject returns different objects with the same xpath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpathnavigator

I'm a bit confused on  UnderlyingObject property in XPathNavigator.

There are 2 issues:
1) in .net version 3.5 and below, UnderlyingObject returns null value by giving the valid xpath in select.
2) in .net version 4 and above, UnderlyingObject returns different instances, though the xpaths that I used are the same.

The problem is demonstrated as following code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.XPath;

    namespace TestConsole
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");
                XPathDocument xdoc = new XPathDocument(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
                var nav = xdoc.CreateNavigator();
                var n1 = nav.SelectSingleNode("/item");
                var n2 = nav.SelectSingleNode("/item");

                if(n1 != n2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("n1 != n2");
                }

                if(n1.UnderlyingObject==null && n2.UnderlyingObject == null)
                {
                    //it steps into here in .net <= 3.5
                    Console.WriteLine("UnderlyingObject are null");
                }
                else if(n1.UnderlyingObject != n2.UnderlyingObject)
                {
                    //it steps into here in .net >= 4.0
                    Console.WriteLine("UnderlyingObject not the same");
                }

                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
```

Result display when it runs with .net version <= 3.5

```
n1 != n2
UnderlyingObject are null
```

Result display when it runs with .net version >= 4

```
n1 != n2
UnderlyingObject not the same
```

In MSDN description, I assume n1.UnderlyingObject == n2.UnderlyingObject as they are queried with the same xpath.

According to  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.UnderlyingObject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) remarks, it says

> The UnderlyingObject property should preserve object identity and should only be used to return objects that have a one-to-one correspondence to their respective overlaid items. A user should always get the same object on successive visits to the same node using the same XPathNavigator object or a cloned one.

Please help :(

Comment: Interestingly. However, "should" does not mean "must". If the `XPathNavigator` create directly on the `XmlDocument` then objects are equal.